# sonarqube issues shows closed items when unresolved resolution is selected

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-web

I have sonarqube 5.3 running and one of the projects is showing incorrect report. Other projects are fine.

On the dashboard of the problem project it shows there are 9 Blocker issues. Clicking on this takes me to the issues page where it shows total 21 issues. The list of issues includes items that has been marked as "Closed(fixed)", which are the extra items. In the issues page, I only have "Blocker" under the Severity and "Unresolved" under the Resolution field checked.

Can you please help to identify why this project's issues page is not showing issues properly based on the filters? Thanks,

Comment: Could you check that the search issue WS http://[SonarQube host]/api/issues/search?severities=BLOCKER&resolved=false&componentKeys=[Project Key] is returning you nine issues ?

Comment: Thank you for Julien for your suggestion. I ran that query in the browser, and that's returning both closed and open issues. Right now it's returning 20 issues in total. GUI is also showing 20 issues.

Comment: Could you run an analysis of the project and check if the issue still exists ?

Comment: actually that's already part of the continuous integration process. We use git for source control. So, whenever new changes are pushed to the master branch, the build process automatically runs full analysis on the project. And this project is quite busy. So, analysis is already being run quite often. This is the only project that is having this issue so far.

Comment: Ok, then you should stop your server, remove your /data/es folder, and start the server again. It will clean elastic search data, and it will be feed at startup.

Comment: Great!! That resolved the issue. Thank you Julien.

Comment: Great ! I'll add an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are some inconsistencies between the issues table and the issues index in elastic search.

The only way to fix it is to  :

1. Stop SonarQube
2. Delete /data/es folder
3. Start SonarQube

Comment: This doesn't solved my issue. is there any other alternative through which i can solve it. I am using sonar 5.6.1

Comment: Could you please open another thread and describe exactly what is you issue (please provide at least use case, server's log and any other information that could help us understand your issue) ? Thanks